# Checking if characters belong in an array (beginner C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, comparison, character

I need to write a program that asks for a three character input and then checks successively if the first, second, then third character belongs in the alphabet (either lowercase or uppercase).
What I have so far is this

```
char v1, v2, v3;
cout << "Enter 3-character identifier: ";
cin >> v1 >> v2 >> v3;

if ((v1 != 'a')&&(v1!='b'))
    cout << v1 << v2 << v3 <<" is an invalid input, check first character\n";
else if (v2 != 'a')
    cout << v1 << v2 << v3 << "Invalid input, check second character\n";
else (v3 != 'a');
    cout << v1 << v2 << v3 << "Invalid input, check third character\n";
```

I'm testing if I can compare the character to the alphabet by asking if it's not equal to every upper and lower case letter individually, but that sounds awful so I stopped at 'b'. I can't seem to compare the characters to an array or a string (shows error), which is the extent of my C++ knowledge. I also can't seem to work the "else" function to only apply when the first two conditions are false. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with the ASCII character set? What it is, and what are its properties? Are you familiar with the `isalpha` function from the C library?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have not learned those yet, would you mind explaining how the 'isalpha' function could work for my question?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In today's lecture we went over the 'while' function. So far we've gone over 'if/else' functions and very general information like data types. This assignment is due in a week, with just one more lecture between then so this difficulty level makes even less sense to me than it does to you. But if you can't answer my **_general_** question thanks anyways.

Comment: The only context in which a `while` loop would make sense here is to read one character at a time. If so: yes, a `while` loop can be used to read each character; then additional code checks if its a letter; and in this manner determines if all characters "belong in the alphabet". Perhaps your instructor also intended for you to put the entire alphabet in an array, and then use another `while` loop to compare each read character against each character from the array, and in that manner implement this task? It's not possible to state, authoritatively, how you are expected to write your program.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `isalpha()` function for the same. Since you mentioned that you have gone through only basic concepts like *if/else* yet so, you may try this way where I've used only the if/else conditions with `isalpha()` function to check consecutively whether the provided inputs are characters respectively or not.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a,b,c;

    cin>>a>>b>>c;

    if(isalpha(a) && isalpha(b) && isalpha(c) == 1)
    {
        cout<<"All of them are characters."<<endl;
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 1 && isalpha(b) ==1 && isalpha(c) == 0)
    {
        cout<<"The third input is not a valid alphabet.";
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 0 && isalpha(b) == 1 && isalpha(c) == 1)
    {
        cout<<"The first input is not a valid alphabet.";
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 1 && isalpha(b) == 0 && isalpha(c) == 1)
    {
        cout<<"The second input is not  valid alphabet.";
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 0 && isalpha(b) == 0 && isalpha(c) == 1)
    {
        cout<<"The first and second inputs are not valid alphabets.";
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 0 && isalpha(b) == 1 && isalpha(c) == 0)
    {
        cout<<"The first and third inputs are not valid alphabets.";
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 1 && isalpha(b) == 0 && isalpha(c) == 0)
    {
        cout<<"The second and third inputs are not valid alphabets.";
    }
    else if(isalpha(a) == 0 && isalpha(b) == 0 && isalpha(c) == 0)
    {
        cout<<"All of them are not valid alphabets.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to include `<cctype>` header file.
[Check out the output file here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk1PX.png)

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm a new contributor so I can't upvote just yet but you're a life saver. I tried what you suggested but only asked isalpha for individual variables rather than asking one at a time if a is true/false, b is true/false, c is true/false etc. I made it so if a simply is false, that cout would be a failure message for character one and so forth. Your reply ended what was three days worth of pain, you have all of my thanks!!